# PutObject access denied for a cross account setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am setting up a **cross-account** between two AWS accounts, and I'd like account B to be able to push files/logs to account A. I have an S3 bucket encrypted with **KMS encryption** sitting in account A.

The bucket in **account A** has the attached policy in it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::00000000:role/some-role-in-account-B"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3::some-bucket-in-account-A",
                "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket-in-account-A/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In **account B**, I have created a role (some-role-in-account-B) with the below policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket-in-account-A",
                "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket-in-account-A/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have an **instance** in account B in which I have attached the **some-role-in-account-B** role.

Running these from the instance: `aws s3 ls s3://some-bucket-in-account-A` works fine. However, `aws s3 cp some-random-file s3://some-bucket-in-account-A` fails with the error: `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied`. Does anyone knows what I might be missing?

Comment: I'm curious, do you need to actually assign permissions in the account B role since all the permissions you need are already provided in the bucket resource policy?  This isn't related to solving your problem (KMS key permissions), but I'm wondering if the permissions in role B are redundant.

Comment: Seems like it's need according to this blog from AWS https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-cross-account-upload-access/ . I haven't tested it yet without tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant the role from account B access to the KMS key.  See here for more information:  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-denied-error-s3/

Mind you, I don't think you need to grant all the permissions referenced in the article to the role, you should only need to grant the following:

- kms:Encrypt
- kms:GenerateDataKey
- kms:ReEncrypt*

Comment: Thanks, just realized I was missing that! Also, to add to @Ashaman comment, I had to add the additional ```--sse aws:kms``` into the aws s3 cp command and that worked.